# Query never finishes when spelled a certain way

Tags: sql-server

We are running SQL Server 2019 Datacenter edition. Production environment. A user noticed that one widget on the website is timing out. I traced the query using SQL Server Profiler -- it's a fairly simple query generated by Entity Framework.

I tried running the query directly from SSMS - same timeout behavior - the query never completes. What's interesting is if I make any changes to the query text (as trivial as removing square brackets surrounding a table name), the query runs in a second. It's only when that exact SQL is executed, the query gets stuck, and since the query is generated by Entity Framework, I cannot change its text.

My thinking was it's a bad query plan that's stuck in the procedure cache.

Here are the things I tried:

- Recompiled the view used in the query
- Executed the query with OPTION (RECOMPILE)
- Re-computed stats on the underlying table
- Checked the output of sp_who2 for blocks -- none found

Found the plan handle using this SQL:

```
SELECT t.*, r.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
WHERE session_id = 102
```

Then tried this DBCC call with the plan handle:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (0x06000700CFC01905507FE260EB01000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

None of these steps work.

What's interesting is that I can get the plan handle from `dm_exec_sql_text` but that plan doesn't exist in `dm_exec_query_plan` or `dm_exec_cached_plans`.

I was wondering if anybody else experienced the same issue, or if you have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further.

Thank you!

Comment: I would take a look at [sp_blitzcache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/) and try [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) while the query is running, see if any more detail can surface. Maybe try a live execution plan too which might show where it's getting stuck.

Comment: You also mention a *view* above - have you tried [sp_refreshview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: What does Query Store tell you? If it tells you nothing because it's not turned on, that's your first mistake. :)